# What exactly does HIbernate do if it uses JDBC itself

Tags: java, hibernate

I am a beginner in Hibernate and while learning it, I came across the concept that it uses JDBC behind the scenes. If that's the case then what exactly is the use of Hibernate? I am aware of its advantages like HQL, annotations, ORM features etc. So does behind the scenes it's always the JDBC that does the work? What are the separate duties of JDBC and Hibernate?

Answer (score 4):

- Hibernate does the ORM layer

  - mapping objects to SQL statements
  - mapping SQL query results (in the form of `ResultSet`s) to objects
- JDBC does the database connectivity

  - sending SQL statements to a database
  - reading the query results as `ResultSet`s
- the database

  - executes SQL statements to update data
  - executes SQL statements to query the data
  - manages the data and indexes

It's important to note that different databases (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres, H2, HSQLDB, Apache DB) have different driver implementations and therefore need different JDBC drivers. Without using JDBC Hibernate would need to implement these drivers itself.